# react native listview with conditon

Tags: listview, react-native

I want to use conditon with if inside listview in react native, my code is:

```js
    constructor(props) {
      super();
      const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(props.data)
      };
      console.log(props.data)
    }    
render()
{
return (
<ListView
dataSource ={this.state.dataSource}
renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
renderRow={(rowData) => 
<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'#fbeded'}}>
<Text style={{textAlign:'right',alignItems:'flex-end',width:'100%',fontSize:18,paddingTop:10,marginRight:'15%',fontFamily:"B Nazanin+ Bold"}}>{rowData.name}</Text>
<View  style={styles.separator1} />
//how use this condition in listview 
if({rowData.address} !==null)
{
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
<Text style={{textAlign:'right',width:'90%',alignItems:'flex-end',fontSize:18,marginRight:10,marginTop:10,fontFamily:"B Nazanin+ Regular"}}>address
:{rowData.province_name}- {rowData.city_name}- {rowData.address}</Text>
<Icon style={{width:'5%',height:'100%',marginTop:10}}
  name='place'
  color='red'
  />
</View>
}
else
{
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
<Text style={{textAlign:'right',width:'90%',alignItems:'flex-end',fontSize:18,marginRight:10,marginTop:10,fontFamily:"B Nazanin+ Regular"}}>address
:{rowData.province_name}- {rowData.city_name}- {rowData.address}</Text>
<Icon style={{width:'5%',height:'100%',marginTop:10}}
  name='place'
  color='blue'
  />
}
</TouchableOpacity> 
}
/>)
}
```

I change if..else with ?: condition but I can not show my condition inside list and show if and else with toghether.

Comment: I think you should take a look into the React basis: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: try to change only the color attribute like this:
`<Icon style={{width:'5%',height:'100%',marginTop:10}}
  name='place'
  color={rowData.address ? 'red' : 'blue'}
  />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i did below, you can use conditional rendering using conditional operator instead of if else block.

If condition is true first block will execute otherwise after ":" what we wrote it will render.

```js
 {
  (rowData.address.trim() != "" ) ? 
   <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
   <Text 
     style={{textAlign:'right',width:'90%',alignItems:'flexend',fontSize:18,marginRight:10,
     marginTop:10,fontFamily:"B Nazanin+ Regular"}}
   >
   address:{rowData.province_name}- {rowData.city_name}- {rowData.address}
   </Text>
  <Icon 
    style={{width:'5%',height:'100%',marginTop:10}}
    name='place'
    color='red'
   />
  </View>
  :
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
<Text style={{textAlign:'right',width:'90%',alignItems:'flex-end',fontSize:18,marginRight:10,marginTop:10,fontFamily:"B Nazanin+ Regular"}}>address
:{rowData.province_name}- {rowData.city_name}- {rowData.address}</Text>
<Icon style={{width:'5%',height:'100%',marginTop:10}}
  name='place'
  color='blue'
  />

}
```

Comment: i use your answer but that is not work.

Comment: what's the error you are getting.

Comment: they show if and else with toghether in screen.

Answer (score 0):

Usually conditional rendering is done with `? :`. Like so:

`<View>
  { (condition)
     ?
       <Text>Yes</Text>
     :
       <Text>No</Text>
  }
</View>`

If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify your requirement in your question

Comment: your answer work out of listview but in listview does not work,i want to render multi view in condition.

Answer (score 0):

You should export the list item into a separate component and write the if and else statements inside the render, before the return.